# How can I get the data I requested in useEffect on next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm new on next.js and typescript so please understand me even if it's too simple question.
I'm trying to pass props from data I requested in useEffect but it seems I can't just pass it... I've already tried to write 'return scheduleList' in the function but it also didn't work.

```js
useEffect((): (() => void) => {
    return async () => {
      const scheduleData = await getDocs(collection(db, "schedule"));
      let scheduleList: object[] = [];
      scheduleData.forEach((schedule) =>
        scheduleList.push({ id: schedule.id, ...schedule.data() }),
      );
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Title>
        <h2>Class schedule</h2>
        <Button onClick={() => router.push("/add")}>Add Class Schedule</Button>
      </Title>
      <Timetable scheduleList={scheduleList}/> // error
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use useState for storing the scheduleList.

```
...
const [scheduleList, setScheduleList] = React.useState<scheduleList type>([]);
...
useEffect(() => {
    async const fetch = () => {
      const scheduleData = await getDocs(collection(db, "schedule"));
      let scheduleList: object[] = [];
      scheduleData.forEach((schedule) =>
        scheduleList.push({ id: schedule.id, ...schedule.data() }),
      );
      setScheduleList(scheduleList);
    };

    fetch();
}, []);
```

Albert

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I'm a bit embrassed that I've forgot this basic thing... Really thank you!